# CefSharp javascript injection

Tags: c#, javascript, cefsharp

I'm trying to inject javascript to the head of the document after page is loaded:

```
var browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
browserSettings.TextAreaResizeDisabled = true;
var webView= new WebView("about:blank", browserSettings);
webView.EvaluateScript("var script = document.createElement('script')"); // Line 1
webView.EvaluateScript("script.src='http://domain.my/scripts/my.js'");   // Line 2
webView.EvaluateScript("document.body.appendChild(script)");             // Line 3
```

After evaluting script line 1 and 2 I can see script variable in dev tools. But when I try to execute line 3 I recieve exception:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in CefSharp.dll`

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use **ExecuteScript** instead of EvaluteScript.